# How to use sqlalchemy to query in many-to-many relation?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

To get a member list in current organization, i used following statement,

```
from ..members import members
from flask.ext.login import current_user
from app.common.database import db_session

@members.route("/", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def index():
    datas = db_session.query(Group_has_Person).filter(Group_has_Person.group.organization==current_user.organization).all()
```

but a exception threw out at runtime: AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Group_has_Person.group has an attribute 'organization'

how to get the member list in a right way? the code below is about model definition:

```
    class Organization(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'Organization'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
        title = Column(String(45), nullable = False)
        logo = Column(String(256), nullable = False)
        contact_name = Column(String(45), nullable = False)
        contact_phone = Column(String(45), nullable = False)
        created_time = Column(DateTime, nullable = False, default = datetime.now())
        User_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.id'))
        user = relationship("User", back_populates="organization")
        groups = relationship("Group", back_populates="organization")

    class Group(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'Group'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
        title = Column(String(45), nullable = False)
        teacher = Column(String(45), nullable = True)
        contact = Column(String(45), nullable = True)
        created_time = Column(DateTime, nullable = False, default = datetime.now())
        status = Column(Integer, nullable = False, default = 1)
        Organization_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Organization.id'))
        organization = relationship("Organization", back_populates="groups")
        members = relationship("Group_has_Person", back_populates="group")

    class Person(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'Person'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
        nickname = Column(String(45), nullable = False)
        avatar = Column(String(256), nullable = False)
        gender = Column(Integer, nullable = False)
        birthday = Column(DateTime, nullable = False)
        User_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.id'))
        user = relationship("User", back_populates="person")
        groups = relationship("Group_has_Person", back_populates="person")

    class Group_has_Person(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'Group_has_Person'
        Group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Group.id'), primary_key = True)
        Person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Person.id'), primary_key = True)
        created_time = Column(DateTime, nullable = False, default = datetime.now())
        status = Column(Integer, nullable = False, default = 0)
        group = relationship("Group", back_populates="members")
        person = relationship("Person", back_populates="groups")
```

table scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE 'Group' (
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'title' varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '班级名称',
  'teacher' varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '辅导老师',
  'contact' varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '联系方式',
  'created_time' datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '创建时间',
  'status' int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '状态：-1-删除 1-正常',
  'Organization_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  KEY 'fk_Classes_Organization1_idx' ('Organization_id'),
  CONSTRAINT 'fk_Classes_Organization1' FOREIGN KEY ('Organization_id') REFERENCES 'Organization' ('id') ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='班级';

CREATE TABLE 'Person' (
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'User_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'nickname' varchar(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  'avatar' varchar(256) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  'gender' int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  'birthday' datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  KEY 'fk_Person_User1_idx' ('User_id'),
  CONSTRAINT 'fk_Person_User1' FOREIGN KEY ('User_id') REFERENCES 'User' ('id') ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='个人';

CREATE TABLE 'Group_has_Person' (
  'Group_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'Person_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'created_time' datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '加入时间',
  'status' int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '状态 0-申请 1-成功',
  PRIMARY KEY ('Group_id','Person_id'),
  KEY 'fk_Group_has_Person_Person1_idx' ('Person_id'),
  KEY 'fk_Group_has_Person_Group1_idx' ('Group_id'),
  CONSTRAINT 'fk_Group_has_Person_Group1' FOREIGN KEY ('Group_id') REFERENCES 'Group' ('id') ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT 'fk_Group_has_Person_Person1' FOREIGN KEY ('Person_id') REFERENCES 'Person' ('id') ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Show your user table

Comment: Use `db_session.query(Group_has_Person).filter(Group_has_Person.Group_id==current_user.organization).all()` ofcourse  `current_user.organization` should be just id of the Group.

Comment: @MikhailKashkin but the object Group and the object Organization are not the same thing, one organization has many groups, there is a one-to-many relationship between them.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my question by the following statement:

```
datas = db_session.query(Group_has_Person).join(Group).filter(Group.organization==current_user.organization).all()
```